# Creating new matrix from dataframe and matrix in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, similarity

I have a dataframe `df` which looks like this:

```
    id1  id2  weights
0   a    2a   144.0
1   a    2b   52.5
2   a    2c   2.0
3   a    2d   1.0
4   a    2e   1.0
5   b    2a   2.0
6   b    2e   1.0
7   b    2f   1.0
8   b    2b   1.0
9   b    2c   0.008
```

And a similarity matrix `mat` between the elements of the `id2` column:

```
    2a    2b   2c   2d   2e   2f
2a  1     0.5  0.7  0.2  0.1  0.3
2b  0.5   1    0.6  0.4  0.3  0.4
2c  0.7   0.6  1    0.1  0.4  0.2
2d  0.2   0.4  0.1  1    0.8  0.7
2e  0.1   0.3  0.4  0.8  1    0.8
2f  0.3   0.4  0.2  0.7  0.8  1
```

Now I would like to create a similarity matrix between the elements of `id1` and the elements from `id2`. For that I consider the elements of `id1` as barycentres of the corresponding elements of `id2` ind my dataframe `df` (with the corresponding `weights`).

My first attempt to do that is with loops (aouch):

```
ids = df.id1.unique()
output = pd.DataFrame(columns = mat.columns,index = ids)
for id in ids:
    df_slice = df.loc[df.id1 == id]
    to_normalize = df_slice.weights.sum()
    temp = mat.loc[df_slice.id2]
    for art in df_slice.id2:
        temp.loc[art] *= df_slice.ix[df_slice.id2 == art,'weights'].values[0]
        temp.loc[art] /= (1.*to_normalize)
    output.loc[id] = temp.sum()
```

But of course this is way not pythonic, and takes ages (`timeit` for these small matrix showed `21.3ms` not computable for a 10k-rows `df` and 3k by 3k `mat`). What would be a more clean/efficient way to do it?

Desired output:

```
    2a          2b          2c          2d          2e          2f
a   0.857606    0.630424    0.672319    0.258354    0.163342    0.329676
b   0.580192    0.540096    0.520767    0.459425    0.459904    0.559425
```

And is there a way to compute another similarity matrix between the elements of `id1` (from this data)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following clocks in at 6–7ms (vs. around 30ms that your approach takes on my machine).

```
import io

import pandas as pd


raw_df = io.StringIO("""\
  id1  id2  weights
0   a    2a   144.0
1   a    2b   52.5
2   a    2c   2.0
3   a    2d   1.0
4   a    2e   1.0
5   b    2a   2.0
6   b    2e   1.0
7   b    2f   1.0
8   b    2b   1.0
9   b    2c   0.008
""")
df = pd.read_csv(raw_df, delim_whitespace=True)

raw_mat = io.StringIO("""\
    2a    2b   2c   2d   2e   2f
2a  1     0.5  0.7  0.2  0.1  0.3
2b  0.5   1    0.6  0.4  0.3  0.4
2c  0.7   0.6  1    0.1  0.4  0.2
2d  0.2   0.4  0.1  1    0.8  0.7
2e  0.1   0.3  0.4  0.8  1    0.8
2f  0.3   0.4  0.2  0.7  0.8  1
""")
mat = pd.read_csv(raw_mat, delim_whitespace=True)


df['norm'] = df.groupby('id1')['weights'].transform('sum')

m = pd.merge(df, mat, left_on='id2', right_index=True)
m[mat.index] = m[mat.index].multiply(m['weights'] / m['norm'], axis=0)

output = m.groupby('id1')[mat.index].sum()
output.columns.name = 'id2'
print(output)
```

Output:

```
id2        2a        2b        2c        2d        2e        2f
id1                                                            
a    0.857606  0.630424  0.672319  0.258354  0.163342  0.329676
b    0.580192  0.540096  0.520767  0.459425  0.459904  0.559425
```

Comment: You're a genius, now on my original dataframe it takes less than 2 seconds... It scales perfectly, upvoted and accepted, thank you!

Comment: Ok my bad, it works fine in my sample (1% of my dataframe), but takes 10 minutes on the big one. And when I try to reapply it in order to get a matrix `id1`/`id1` I get a memorryerror..